# Biblatex not compiling my code correctly - URL error

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, errors

I'm trying to compile my code with biblatex, however I get this error message:

> WARN - Entry fluenttut does not parse correctly
>
> ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\D9jOf6Klxg\References.bib_12344.utf8, line 5, syntax error: found "url", expected end of entry ("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")

My References.bib looks like this:

```
@online{fluenttut, 
title={FLUENT Learning Modules}, 
author={Weidner, S and Wallingford, M P},
year=2017
url={https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/SIMULATION/FLUENT+Learning+Modules}, 
urldate={24-11-2017},, 
organization={Cornell University}}
```

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{References}

\begin{document}
\cite{fluenttut}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I already updated MiKTex to the newest version, I changed the compiler in Texstudio to Biber, I emptied my temporary files and also tried with a new copy of the original document. I'm still receiving this error :(

What am I doing wrong:

Comment: You need a comma after the `year` (which you should wrap in braces): `year = {2017},`. You also have two commas after `urldate`, one is enough there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your commas:

```
@online{fluenttut, 
title={FLUENT Learning Modules}, 
author={Weidner, S and Wallingford, M P},
year=2017   <-- missing comma here
url={https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/SIMULATION/FLUENT+Learning+Modules}, 
urldate={24-11-2017},, <-- double comma
organization={Cornell University}}
```